# VBA retrieve hyperlink target sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-2013

I'm trying to retrieve the sheet reference location from a hyperlink that's in a cell

The following doesn't seem to work as `test` doesn't return anything, even though `G8` points to Sheet: **KO** in Cell `A19`

```
test = Range("G8").Hyperlinks(3).Address
```

Now if I run the following:

```
For Each hl In Sheets("LIST").Hyperlinks
    MsgBox "Range " & hl.Range.Address & " addr " & _
            hl.Address & " text " & hl.TextToDisplay
Next hl
```

It cycles through and finds the correct address but I can't seem to work out how to detect the sheet it's pointing. Also the loop is a bit of a mess because it errors out once it has found the first and only hyperlink in this situation. And it's not always specific for G8. I guess I could just throw an if statement in and exit the for loop early.

Regardless of that, I can't find anywhere in stackoverflow, google, microsofts "hyperlinks" docs a way to get the sheet name.

**See below sample illustration:**
[image: sample pic]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SubAddress` is what you want:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim hl As Hyperlink, r As Range

    Set hl = ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks(1)

    Set r = Application.Evaluate(hl.SubAddress)

    Debug.Print "Sheet: '" & r.Parent.Name & "'", "Range:" & r.Address()

End Sub
```

Comment: Faster way I can do: `r = Split(Range("G8").Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress, "!")(0)` ?

Comment: @Ryflex That is just another way to get the sheet name. But the `SubAddress` from which you can pull the info you need solves the issue you described above.

Comment: @Ryflex - if you use Split then you need to account for single quotes when the sheet name has spaces: e.g. `'Shee    t1'!A1`