# Get explicit sheet hyperlink from cell VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to extract the hyperlink of an excel cell with hyperlink to another sheet in the same workbook. Is there a way to do it? In example:

```
Cell A1: "HPI" (with hyperlink to Sheet HPI)
result -> Cell B1: HPI
```

I found this formula but it's not working with reference to another sheet.

```
Function GetURL(cell As range, Optional default_value As Variant)
'Lists the Hyperlink Address for a Given Cell
'If cell does not contain a hyperlink, return default_value
 If (cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count <> 1) Then
      GetURL = default_value
Else
      GetURL = cell.range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hyperlink *within* a document uses [the `.Subaddress` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.subaddress), not the `.Address` property:

```
Function GetDestination(Target As Range, Optional default_value As Variant) AS Variant
'Lists the Hyperlink Address or Subaddress for a Given Cell
'If cell does not contain a hyperlink, return default_value
    If (Target.Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks.Count <> 1) Then
        GetDestination = default_value
    Else
        With Target.Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks(1)
            If Len(.Address)>0 Then
                GetDestination = .Address
            Else
                GetDestination = .SubAddress
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, quick question: is there a way to remove the reference to the cell and just get the sheet name directly within the function?

Comment: ++ nicely explained :) @Jordan_b you mean `GetDestination = split(.SubAddress,"!")(0)`

Comment: or [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574065/vba-retrieve-hyperlink-target-sheet) @Jordan_b

Comment: @Jordan_b I would recommend `Range(.Subaddress).Worksheet.Name` - this will *also* work if your Hyperlink points at a Named Range instead of just a Cell Reference, while `Split(..)` would fail